# sort by number of words of a field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a string field in my document. Now I need to sort my documents based on the word counts of that field. How do I accomplish that in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach to this would be to use the [token count type](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-core-types.html#token_count).
But then we need to make sure that we are not disrupting the orginal string. For this , we need to use [multi field](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/mapping-multi-field-type.html) and add additional field to keep track of the tokens alone.

Now a mapping like below should work best for us

```
{
    "tweet" : {
        "properties" : {
            "name" : {
                "type" : "multi_field",
                "fields" : {
                    "wordCount" : {"type" : "token_count"},
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51590179/search-part-of-string-with-elasticseach?noredirect=1#comment90147346_51590534

Answer (score 0):

Use **[term aggregation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)** like as :

```
curl -H GET http://loclahost:9200/index name/_search?pretty=1 -d' 
    {
        "aggs": {
            "genders": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "gender"
                }
            }
        }
    }'
```

> Note : for curl command [check this](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/search-search.html)

Here search for field `gender` and get result of all gender in aggregation bucket and default result is sorted order.

Comment: This works for single-word fields but fails when multiple tokens are present as each token is counted separately. `Hello world`, `Hello my name is dave` -> `Hello` x 2, `name` x 1, `dave` x 1, `world` x 1 (`my` and `is` may or may not be stripped out depending on the analyzer you use).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to store the token count alongside the original field. See the documentation in the Core Types here: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-core-types.html#token_count

Then you would sort by field.word_count (where field is the 'parent' property).