# Search part of string with ElasticSeach

Tags: elasticsearch, search, match

In ElasticSearch, I tried to makeit search for a part of a word.
My example data is

```
{
  "_id" : "1",
  "name" : "Nopales",
}
{
  "_id" : "2",
  "name" : "ginger ale",
}
{
  "_id" : "3",
  "name" : "Kale",
}
{
  "_id" : "4",
  "name" : "Triticale Flour Whole Grain",
}
```

and the request is to find the matching words with the word "ale is"

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
                "query_string" : {"default_field" : "name", "query" : "*ale*"}
            } 

}
```

and it returns the results like

```
Kale, Triticale Flour Whole Grain, ginger ale, Nopales
```

but the best match is ginger ale, which contains the exact word, then kale, then nopales based on word counts then Triticale Flour Whole Grain.
Anyone have idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `*ale` . In your query it searching for `ale` in all values of `name` field. And these all values `Kale, Triticale Flour Whole Grain, ginger ale, Nopales` contains `ale`. When you will query with `*ale`, It will search for string which ending with `ale`. You can also use like this `"query" : "(*ale)OR(ale*)"` for different kind of wildcards.

Comment: I want to check for relevance also, if any words starts with ale then it has more priority, here ginger ale, the second word is an exact match

Comment: You can specify your query with 'OR' condition like this  ```"query" : "(*ale)OR(ale*)"```. You can modify according to your need.

Comment: any method to sort it by word count?

Comment: may be this can help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782450/elasticsearch-order-by-string-length